# chrome extension - send message from content script to background page and back to content script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have no idea if this is the most efficient way of doing what I'm trying to do, if isn't by all means tell me.

I'm building a chrome extension that is supposed to loop through each word on the page, and then compare it to a list of 12,000 elements in an array. I managed to make it work on the content script page, but to my dismay, it takes about 7 seconds to load my content script because of all the looping that is taking place. This isn't ideal, obviously. So I had the idea of sending all the `p` tags to the background page, where it then compares the `p` words to the array, and once it figures out which match, it sends a message back to the content script with a smaller array of just the words that are located both in the `p` tags and in my array.

Now my question is, is this possible? Will it reduce the load time? Is this efficient?

One final question: My manifest is using a background page in the form of `html` but if I wanted to also use a background script Google doesn't allow that, so can I place my background script in the background page `html` file and will it load that script?

Comment: possible duplicate of [chrome extension - best method of reducing load time while using content scripts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30956709/chrome-extension-best-method-of-reducing-load-time-while-using-content-scripts)

Comment: Welcome to SO.  For your last paragraph: SO doesn't work well with multiple questions in one.  But: your background html can definitely include a background.js.  You can also skip the html entirely, and Chrome will make it for you.

Comment: That's hard to tell without more context. What you're suggesting adds lots of overhead (serializing the DOM, exchanging messages with the background page), and if it takes 7 second to process all tags in the tab, moving it to the extension's background page isn't that much of an improvement in terms of user experience. You'd better try to improve the performance of your application. Use the profiler of the devtools to find out the bottleneck, and fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your first question, yes it is possible to do this. It will execute your heavy treatment in an the background (and hidden) page. The page with the content script will not freeze this way.

You can do it like this :

In your background script :

```
function heavyStuff(request, sender, sendResponse)
{

    ...
    doSomeThing(request)
    doOtherThing()
    ...

    sendResponse(youreSmallerArray)
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(heavyStuff)
```

And in your content script :

```
function manageResponse(smallerArray)
{
    ...
    doWhatYouWant(smallerArray)
    ...
}

arrayOfP = $("p")
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(arrayOfP, manageResponse)
```

So it will do what you want, but are you sure of what you're doing? Perhaps your algorithm have to be improved?

For more information about Chrome's message system, you can read the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

Especially if you have to send lot of messages, look for the long-lived connections section.

---

For the second question, you can replace in the manifest the background page attribute by that :

```
"background":
{
    "scripts":
    [
        "background.js",
        "otherScript.js",
        ....
        "theLastScript.js"
    ]
}
```

Chrome will create automaticaly a background page with this scripts included (in the same order).

PS : The next time you post on this site, please ask only one question at a time ;-)

Comment: _Your_. Not _you're_.

Comment: It's fine, not everyone here speaks perfect English. It's just that it's one of the most irritating mistakes. See [here](http://www.yourvsyoure.com/).

Comment: @Xan Haha ^^ I will be careful about it from now :-)

Comment: Are you allowed to sendMessage a jQuery object?

Comment: @Teepeemm You can send any type. It can be an Object, a String, an Array, an integer, or any what else you wants

Comment: "A message can contain any valid JSON object (null, boolean, number, string, array, or [JSON] object)." from https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging

Comment: @Teepeemm Yes exactly ;-)

Comment: So a jQuery object is a JSON object?  I didn't know that.

Comment: @Teepeemm JSON means JavaScript Object Notation, so yes, any javascript object can be a JSON object. You can send any javascript object like JQuery ones but also your own object like plain objects ;-)

Comment: @Teepeemm And if you look well it's exactly what I do in my example

Comment: (Almost) Any JSON object is a javascript object, but the reverse isn't true.  JSON isn't allowed to have circular references or [Date, Error, Regular Expression, Function, and undefined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Unsupported_native_data_types).  Some of these are allowed to be in a sendMessage, but not circular references or Functions.  But my testing has convinced me that jQuery objects are allowed.

Comment: Date, Error and Regular Expression passed for me... But yes function are not allowed but object with methods are can be use instead

Comment: @EmrysMyrooin Thanks for the help! This is really useful. As for the second question I had, what if I already have a `background page` that is being called int he manifest... How can I call a script since Google doesn't allow both `background pages` and `background scripts`..?

Comment: Yes you can. Simply add a script balise linking your script as a normal HTML page :-)